# After updating Xcode 7.3, Error An App ID is not available. while creating iPA file for testing app

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, xcode7

I am trying to export ADHoc app iPA for Testing an Production APP and got the following error under the bundle ID I provided (already using in production app). An App ID with Identifier 'com.xxx.xxx' is not available. Please enter a different string. What does this mean? I am not trying to add a brand new App ID, of course it does exist in Production also. What am I missing? I do not remember experience the problem last time I create an iPA. But this happened after Xcode 7.3 update, Because of this problem i changed my distribution Provisioning profile and tried, but still its not coming..

I am able to install on my ios device but when I'm trying to create iPA with my apple id it coming like "An App ID with Identifier 'com.xxx.xxx' is not available. Please enter a different string"

And Xcode automatically selected another team name which is accessible to my apple ID. what should i do??

Comment: shankar are you tried that duplicate answers

Comment: Yes i tried... But still i'm getting An App ID with Identifier 'com.xxx.xxx' is not available. Please enter a different string. Xcode don't matching the team also.

Comment: @Anbu-karthik : Can i reinstall Xcode 7.3 because after updating only I'm facing this issue ??

Comment: ok do like , open ur account on apple portal, and generate the certificate and install

Comment: I reinstalled Xcode and certificates it still give's same error